# Вроде код работает но е олимп не хочет его полностью принимать

Tags: python

Нужно чтобы при вводе натурального числа (факториального (например 120)) выводился факториал этого числа (то есть !5 в данном случае)
Входные данные: только факториальные числа, значение n! (1 ≤ n ≤ 2000). [Ссылка на задачу](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/62).
Помогите пожалуйста!

```
n = int(input())
f = 0
i = 1
while n % i == 0:
    f += 1
    n /= i
    i += 1
print(f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в общем-то всё верно. За исключением одного нюанса - надо использовать целочисленное деление `//`. Т.е. написать `n //= i`.
Ну и можно использовать всего одну переменную для счётчика. Т.к. `f` у вас в любой момент времени равен `i-1`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как я только не заметил..